# SignatureDoesNotMatch on S3 PresignPutObject

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I've got a golang backend in which I want to generate a signed s3 URL so that a React frontend can upload to. When using the generated URL, I'm always getting a 403 `SignatureDoesNotMatch`.

Here's how I generate the URL on the backend:

```
    client := s3.NewFromConfig(aws.Config{
        Region:      cfg.Region,
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(cfg.AccessKeyId, cfg.SecretAccessKey, ""),
    })

    presignClient := s3.NewPresignClient(client, func(opts *s3.PresignOptions) {
        opts.Expires = time.Duration(60 * int(time.Second))
    })

    headOut, err := client.HeadBucket(ctx, &s3.HeadBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("bucket-name-example"),
    }) // THIS RETURNS NO ERROR - AWS SECRETS ARE GOOD

    req, err := presignClient.PresignPutObject(ctx, &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("bucket-name-example"),
        Key:    aws.String("randomFileName"),
    })

    return req.URL // Using this URL in the Frontend
```

And on the UI I do:

```
return await fetch(signedURLFromBackend, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", // removing this doesn't fix it
    },
    body: file,
  })
```

On AWS, I'm using an IAM user with all s3 policies right now (testing). The S3 bucket has

- ACLs disabled
- Following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1675697346173",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1675697339589",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::userled-assets-library/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Following CORS settings:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
        "AllowedMethods": ["PUT","HEAD","GET"],
        "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```